# Google Drive Permissions IOS

Tags: sdk, google-drive-api, computer-science

So, basically this lets me open the Google Drive and asks for a sign in, then loads a number of files in your drive. I want to know how to list and modify permissions. Any help would be appreciated! thanks

```
 import GoogleAPIClientForREST
 import GoogleSignIn
 import UIKit



class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials by
// resetting the iOS simulator or uninstall the app.
private let scopes = [kGTLRAuthScopeDriveReadonly]

private let service = GTLRDriveService()
let signInButton = GIDSignInButton()
let output = UITextView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure Google Sign-in.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = scopes
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

    // Add the sign-in button.
    view.addSubview(signInButton)

    // Add a UITextView to display output.
    output.frame = view.bounds
    output.isEditable = false
    output.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
    output.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    output.isHidden = true
    view.addSubview(output);
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        showAlert(title: "Authentication Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        self.service.authorizer = nil
    } else {
        self.signInButton.isHidden = true
        self.output.isHidden = false
        self.service.authorizer = user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
        listFiles()
    }
}

// List up to 10 files in Drive
func listFiles() {
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
    query.pageSize = 3
    service.executeQuery(query,
                         delegate: self,
                         didFinish: #selector(displayResultWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
    )
}

func listPermissions() {
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_PermissionsList.query(withFileId: "1Tb9PY4fNl2XRPe5k-ZkqTZG4TLi-s_sC-Kvo82lRo9g")
    query.pageSize = 3
    service.executeQuery(query,
                         delegate: self,
                         didFinish: #selector(displayPermissionsWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:))
    )
}

//1Tb9PY4fNl2XRPe5k-ZkqTZG4TLi-s_sC-Kvo82lRo9g

// Process the response and display output
func displayResultWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
                             finishedWithObject result : GTLRDrive_FileList,
                             error : NSError?) {

    if let error = error {
        showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    var text = "";
    if let files = result.files, !files.isEmpty {
        text += "Files:\n\n"
        for file in files {
            text += "\(file.name!)(\(file.identifier!))\n\n" //(\(file.identifier!))
        }
    } else {
        text += "No files found."
    }
    output.text = text
}


// Process the response and display output
func displayPermissionsWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket,
                             finishedWithObject result : GTLRDriveQuery_PermissionsList,
                             error : NSError?) {

    if let error = error {
        showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    var text = "";
    if let files = result.files, !files.isEmpty {
        text += "Files:\n\n"
        for file in files {
            text += "\(file.name!)(\(file.identifier!))\n\n" //(\(file.identifier!))
        }
    } else {
        text += "No files found."
    }
    output.text = text
}


// Helper for showing an alert
func showAlert(title : String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert
    )
    let ok = UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style: UIAlertActionStyle.default,
        handler: nil
    )
    alert.addAction(ok)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, I hope this document regarding [permission.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/list) helps you get the list you need, and [permission.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/update) to modify permission.

> Permissions
>
> For a list of methods for this resource, see the end of this page.
>
> Resource representations
>
> A permission for a file. A permission grants a user, group, domain or
>   the world access to a file or a folder hierarchy.

Here is a reference that might help regarding [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions).